# JQuery UI tabs plugin: tabs and content panes in different containers?

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

Is there no way it's possible to have the tabs and the content panes in two separate containers using jQueryUI tabs?

I have this layout:

```
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| A            | B                                                      |
| Link         | Tabs                                                   |
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| C            | D                                                      |
|              |                                                        |
| <- Animate ->|  Content panes                                         |
|              |                                                        |
|              |                                                        |
|              |                                                        |
|              |                                                        |
|              |                                                        |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Clicking the link collapses C-container and thereby expanding D-container with the tabs panes. I would much prefer designing my html something like this:

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="left" /> <!--A-->
    <div class="right" /> <!--B (tabs ul goes in here) -->
</div>
<div class="bottom">
    <div class="left" /> <!--C-->
    <div class="right" /> <!--D (content panes goes in here) -->
</div>
```

but that'll throw a "mismatching fragment identifier" error from jQueryUI Tabs.

Is there no work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of theming and design constraints this isn't possible with jQuery UI Tabs.
but you can achive this as shown in this [example](http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/standalone/tools/tabbed-players.html)

Comment: I hope to have come a bit of the way by positioning the tabs fixed. Just hope it performs ok when I start doing the animation in IE 8 :-( Thanks for the link!